# Is having a static int for classes to identify objects good practice for OO?

Tags: java

I have a scenario where there are several "Person" classes and each Person object has an attribute String "name".

My coursework requires me to have a class where a menu lists the names of each Person object and users can input a name and then a method will search for the Person object where the "name" attribute equals the string in-putted by the user.

Now, my lecturer said he will give extra marks for creative coding practices, and I had an idea to have a static int called "numberOfPersons" in the Person class that will increment in the Person constructor. The value of the "numberOfPersons" int is assigned to an extra attribute named "id" in the constructor also.

Then, when the menu is displayed, it displays a list with the id and the name following it. So it would be like..

1. Sally
2. John
3. Bob

And then ask the user for the person id. I thought this would be good practice as it is less input to type, it prevents the need for checking case-sensitivity and reduces the chance of spelling-mistakes. Is there anything wrong with doing this? I have searched around google but can't quite figure out what to search for. My lecturer wants to see creative programming techniques and good practice, is there anything redundant about this?

Thanks.

Comment: what if you have a large number of Persons and the user doesn't know the ID? i'd have two fields for searching - one for Id and one for the name

Comment: What if there is more than one Person with the same name?

Comment: How is the `id` of a person any different than its index in whatever collection you're storing them in?

Comment: You should really post some code.  But overall, this sounds like an acceptable method to assign each person a unique ID#.

Comment: You have to treat the person object as if it is a person in the real world, otherwise it defeats the abstraction. You can identify people by their names but names can overlap. You need an identifier, which in our world would be SSN, well US.

Comment: @blueygh2, I use the search method in the Person constructor which passes the entered username and if the method returns a Person object,  there is already a person with this name and so it throws an exception.

Comment: This link discusses something very similar to what you are suggesting. I suggest giving it a full read, especially the last section. [Java for Beginners: Static Variables — What Are They?](http://www.caveofprogramming.com/frontpage/articles/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they/)

Comment: *search method in the Person constructor* sounds wrong. Do you mean *Person class*? Why would you throw an exception? I think your program should be able to handle this

Comment: @NappaTheSaiyan It is a requirement of the coursework that the Person objects can not have the same name, they are used as references to employees that have to be moved between departments.

Comment: Well then you can store them in a Map<String, Person>, where the key is the name. With no chance of having the same name there wouldn't be any collision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that adding an id to the Person class defeats the abstraction of the Person class. Since it doesn't correspond to any Id the Person has in life.

Since a Person object can't have the same name, there is no reason you can't use a map in your processing.

```
HashMap<String, Person> mapOfPersons = new HashMap<String, Person>()
```

You can then get on the person name, and it will return the corresponding Person object. Now you no longer have to add the Id.

Answer (score 0):

> ...is there anything redundant about this?

I'm assuming, based on how you're printing the `Person`s, that you are storing the objects in an array or some indexed collection. If this is true, your `id` field is just a constant shift from the `Person`'s index in the array/collection. So, if asking the user for an index in a list is the only use for the `id`, then it is redundant.

Comment: But if you have a method that takes a `Person` parameter, and you don't know the index and need to find it, how would you find it except with a possibly time-consuming linear search?  There are often valid reasons to store an index in an object.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think your idea is OK for a course, in general `static` members should be avoided.  In your case, you have a `Person` object to represent each person.  But the entire database of persons is an important entity, conceptually, and it really ought to be its own object.  If you had something like a `PersonDatabase` or `PersonCollection` class, the `numberOfPersons` would be a (non-static) member field of that class (or maybe a method), and you would use that to get the next ID instead of a `static` field.

By the way, putting numbers on menu items and letting users input the number was a very normal way of doing things before we had GUI's, when many users only had consoles capable of displaying text, not graphics.